# Automatic stash/apply changes when changing feature branches

Tags: smartgit

Essentially what I'm looking for is a way to treat each feature branch as a separate repository, as follows in this sample workflow:

1) If my active branch is Feature A, and I have "foo.cpp" modified and want to checkout Feature B, I want SmartGit to automatically stash my changes upon doing so.

2) Piddling around in feature B and then returning to feature A, I want it to stash my changes to feature A, then apply (and likely drop) the feature A stash created in at the tail of step 1.

Is there any way to do this automatically, or am I asking for something ridiculous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SmartGit does not assign stashes to certain branches, but you can simply commit your modifications in *A* as a temporary *WIP* (work-in-progress) commit, then switch to *B*, continue working there, finally commit your changes again as *WIP* and switch back to *A*. Now you have several choices:

- **Local|Undo Last Commit** to "unstash" your previous work;
- just continue working and committing with **Amend** option to the existing *WIP* commit. Once your feature is ready use **Edit Commit Message** in the **Outgoing** view;
- continue working and committing to a new *WIP* commit and once your feature is ready use **Squash Commits** in the **Outgoing** view to compact all your *WIP* commits into one tidy, final commit.

Personally, I prefer the last choice, because having several *WIP* commits lets me better review my progress (and see possible back-and-forth I did when switching between tasks).